# LiveCode: How to change the background color of a cell in a Data Grid

Tags: colors, datagrid, livecode

In a Data Grid table, I would like to change the backgroud color of a "selected" cell.

In the table, the user can select a cell in each row (I used a custom property that I increment each time the user click on the same row). I would like to highlight the selected cell, for instance by changing the bg color of it.

How can I do that ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, thanks to the answer of dunbarx, and with adding the use of "the target".

```
on mouseUp 
    set the opaque of the target to "true"
    set the backColor of the target to "green"
end mouseUp
```

Comment: That is a good insight into the fact that these are just fields, after all. I would still be interested if there is a built-in way to set those properties, assuming that field has focus.

Answer (score 1):

I am fond of saying that I use data grids, but do not understand them.

A dataGrid is just a complex LC object, comprised of other LC objects, groups and behaviors. Each field is designated as, say: fld "Col 1 0002" (first column, second line)

So you could:

```
  on mouseUp
    set the opaque of fld "col 1 0002" to "true"
    set the backColor of fld "col 1 0002" to "red"
  end mouseUp
```

Now there may well be a "native" way of doing this, But I do not know it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! .... but it doesn't work... (no such object error). Meanwhile my problem is actually that I don't know how to get the field corresponding to the cell, in order to change it. I can access the value of the cell, but not the field object.

Comment: Ok I finally found the problem. I had renamed the column of my Data Grid, and it seems that it doesn't work with other names (even if I use the same in the script). It works with pre-defined names such as "Col 1". Thanks for your help! I am working now on expending it to colour the "selected cell", as I asked in the question.

Comment: I think you can delete your other answers, that doesn't really differ from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If I make a new DG and fill it with some tab and return delimited text, my handler turns the designated "cell" red.

I do notice that there was a spurious character after "end mouseUp" in my earlier post. I edited it out, but might this have caused your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have data in the "cell" you are interested in? This method will not work if it is empty. "No such object"? It may be that you need this as well:

```
 on mouseUp
   set the opaque of fld "col 2 0003" of grp "yourDG to "true"
   set the backColor of fld "col 2 0003" of grp "yourDG" to "green"
end mouseUp
```